# Prohibit pagebreak between listoftables and listoffigures

Tags: koma-script

In my document I use KOMA class `scrreprt`. This leads to a new page for each new chapter. It also happens for `\listoftables` and `\listoffigures`. Now I have a special case where I want to suppress the linebreak between these two sections.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures % <-- How to prohibit page break here?
    \listoftables

    \Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

How can I get `\listoftables` and `\listoffigures` at the same page and avoid the page page betweem them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change `style` of sectioning command `\chapter` locally to `style=section`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
{%
  \RedeclareSectionCommand[style=section,indent=0pt]{chapter}%
  \listoftables
}

\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Or you could use option `listof=leveldown`. Then LOT and LOF both use sectioning command `\section`:

```
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addchap{Lists}
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Or with `\cleardoublepage` instead the additional chapter heading "Lists":

```
\documentclass[listof=leveldown]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would prefer the second suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer. I've used the first approach because the LOF and LOT have the same size like TOC. With `listof=leveldown` the size of the headings are little smaller.